# A problem about Markov kernel and the Monotone class theorem

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $f: A\times B \times C \to R $ be a measurabled function, which is also bounded.

And $p:B \times \sigma(C)\to R$  be a Markov kernel.

Prove
$g(x,y)=\int f(x,y,z)dp_y (z)$ is measurable with respect to the product $ \sigma-algebra, \sigma (A) \times\sigma(B)$.

Note: For each $y\in B $, $G (\in \sigma(C)) \to p_y (G)$ is a probability measure; for each $G \in \sigma(C)$.$y(\in B) \to p_y(G)$ is  a measurable function.

My idea: {$E \times F$: $E \in \sigma(A), F\in \sigma(B)$} is a $\pi$-system, so I'm trying to find a collection of real-valued function which can let me use the Monotone class theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Prove the claim for $$f(x,y,z) := 1_E(x) 1_F(y) 1_G(z)$$ where $E \in \sigma(A)$, $F \in \sigma(B)$, $G \in \sigma(C)$.
2. Show that $$\mathcal{D} := \{D \in \sigma(A) \otimes \sigma(B) \otimes \sigma(C); f := 1_D \, \text{satisfies the claim}\}$$ is a Dynkin system. Conclude that $\mathcal{D} = \sigma(A) \otimes \sigma(B) \otimes \sigma(C)$.
3. Let $f \geq 0$ be a bounded measurable function. Then there exists a sequence of step functions $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $f_n \geq 0$ and $f_n \uparrow f$. Deduce from step 2 and the monotone convergence theorem that $$(x,y) \mapsto \int f(x,y,z) \, dp_y(z)$$ is measurable.
4. For general bounded measurable $f$ consider $f = f^+ - f^-$ where $f^+$ and $f^-$ denote the positive and negative part of $f$, respectively.

Comment: I got it! We can use the $\pi - \lambda$theorem on $D$.

Comment: @user147893 Yes, that's correct.